# Flexbox layout on Safari not working in mobile view

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using @angular/flex-layout and @angular/material for my website but I'm having issues Smith my mobile layout when using safari.

This only happens when the window is small enough for the md or xs rules

On Chrome it looks like this:
[image: Chrome]

But on safari it looks like this:
[image: Safari]

Here is a plunk with the code where it happens:
https://embed.plnkr.co/2gh075v8CZ5aU6iA0xYd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out what the issue was.

i had to add `flex: 1 0 auto !important;` to the parent that was not being filled correctly.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using `@angular/flex-layout` try to utilize the existing `fxFlex` Options rather than using CSS to overwrite the styles.

same CSS `flex: 1 0 auto !important` can also be done by `fxFlex="noshrink"`

[Github fxFlex-API](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxFlex-API)