# Angular 7 App styling broken in Safari, Opera & IE, fine in Chrome, Firefox, Vivaldi & Edge

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material-7

I am working on an app for work on both Mac and Windows machines.

I am using a *ngFor to loop through a list of menu items which have icons attached. I have placed a class on each individual menu item so I can style them.

```
Parent Component
<app-application-action class="side-nav__item" fxFlex *ngFor="let action of actions" [showTitle]=true
    [action]="action">
</app-application-action>

Child Component (<app-application-action>)
 <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex class="action-nav__icon-box" fxLayoutAlign="start center">

 <div [ngSwitch]="IconType" fxFlex="nogrow">

  <span fxFlex="nogrow" *ngSwitchCase="0" class="{{ Icon }}"></span>

  <svg fxFlex="nogrow" *ngSwitchCase="1" class="action-nav__icon">
   <use [attr.xlink:href]="Icon"></use>
  </svg>
 </div>

 <div *ngIf="showTitle" fxFlex class="action-nav__title"> 
  <span *ngIf="Count !== undefined" class="action-nav__notification">{{Count}}</span>
  <span>{{Title}}</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Styles

```
.side-nav__item {
padding-bottom: .7rem;
}

.action-nav__icon {
width: 2.3rem;
}
```

This results in the below. First is Chrome/Vivaldi/FireFox/Edge, second is Safari & Opera. I.E has additional issues as I can't even open the material sidenav drawer (that is a separate issue).[image: menu on Chrome/FF/Vivaldi/Edge]
[image: menu on Safari/Opera & IE]

Why are the styles not working correctly on Safari & IE? How can I make CSS rules that only come into affect on a chosen browser?

EDIT: I have found that the containing div has flexbox created by the flex-layout npm package. If I turn off display flex in Safari's css editor the menu looks the same as in Chrome. So now I need to understand how to fix this problem and it should work.

I can't create a Blitz because there is too much client info to take out.

Comment: can you share link or pen ? if not please share bit more of css part. Make sure your nav item is `display:block`  !

Comment: I had the same issue. You should add `flex: 1 1 auto`

Answer (score 0):

Main idea is to replace fxFlex with `fxFlex=100` (or some other value)

There are some multiple answers on StackOverflow for this question. see [Flexbox layout on Safari not working in mobile view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554094/flexbox-layout-on-safari-not-working-in-mobile-view)